# Async request to external api within soap service

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, soap, asmx

I'm trying to write a soap service that returns the wheater based on latitude and longitude of a certain location. I want to request the data from the external openweathermap api using an async httpclient.

When debugging this code, the process suddenly stops at the start of the getResponse function at this line:

```
string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

The output is an empty xml object, even without a soap wrapper.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://cloud4090.weatherProvider.be/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WeatherProvider : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    private const string API_KEY = "80b7844b635e86689430677c077b3ef2";
    private const string Url_weather_forecast = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?" + "lat=@lat@&lon=@lon@&units=metric&appid=" + API_KEY;
    private const string Url_current_weather = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?" + "lat=@lat@&lon=@lon@&units=metric&appid=" + API_KEY;

    static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public WeatherProvider()
    {
        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public async Task<string> getWeatherCurrentAsync(float lat, float lon)
    {
        string url = Url_current_weather.Replace("@lat@", lat.ToString());
        url = url.Replace("@lon@", lon.ToString());

        string response = await getResponse(url);

        return response;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public async Task<string> getWeatherForecastAsync(float lat, float lon)
    {
        string url = Url_weather_forecast.Replace("@lat@", lat.ToString());
        url = url.Replace("@lon@", lon.ToString());

        string response = await getResponse(url);

        return response;
    }


    static async Task<string> getResponse(string url)
    {
        // Call asynchronous network methods in a try/catch block to handle exceptions.
        try
        {
            string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
            return responseBody;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");
            Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ", e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the error message？

Comment: I don't recieve an error message, the process just exitst